# How do I re-color clay pots of my plants?

Tags: indoors, containers, pots

I have several indoor plants in ceramic\clay pots. The pots are now look old & faded. Also, fungus is grown on them.

So, I was thinking to re-color them to get a fresh look. What should I consider in choosing color for pots and coloring technique? or any other thing which I need to consider for this.

Comment: Maybe DIY.SE is better fit for this?

Comment: Well coloring is not difficult. I asked here because answers here will be in favor of my plant's health.

Comment: @theUg this would not be on topic on DIY.SE. they do home improvement only not general DIY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean the pots first, removing any fungal or algal growth, and, if they are terracotta or clay, you can paint those with any water based paint such as emulsion intended for use on walls. You will, though, need to reapply at intervals, and you may need to apply several coats. Best done when the pots are empty, and replant when all the coats of paint have been dry for at least 24 hours.

Comment: Any specific color for plant's pots? Wall emulsion will not harm to plants?

Comment: Provided its a water based paint, it should be fine, but you must allow it to dry thoroughly before planting. As for colour, well that's a matter of personal preference.